# How to read data from URL page that has no HTML tags defined using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to read the content of a page from URL by using the below code in MVC C#

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://example.com/aa/aa");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
using (var response = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (var content = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(content))
{
    var strContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

but I didnot receive any response (the call never returned to strContent)
but when I run the same code using URL : https://google.com/, it worked fine.
I checked the source code for both pages, and found that https://google.com/ has a proper doctype and tags declared but the one I am hitting seems to be a properties file with no tags and doctype defined.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not provide the link to actual target?

Comment: `WebRequest` should not care whether there is a doctype.  I would guess that the page you are visiting has some anti-scraping code built in.  You may need to supply a proper `User-agent` header, or check if some other request authentication is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
     string data = client.DownloadString("www.yourUrl.com");
}
```

Comment: Answers should be more detailed than just a code snippet. Consider to add some details, otherwise it is a low-quality answer.